# Magmi is not importing the images for the existing products

Tags: magento, magmi

I am trying to import images using magmi.

I have the following format of csv

```
    "sku","image","small_image","thumbnail"
    "AIC-BCS-KS10-CRSNTH-CMP","/catalog/product/a/i/aico-bcs-ks10-crsnth-cmp_1.jpg
","/catalog/product/a/i/aico-bcs-ks10-crsnth-cmp_1.jpg","/catalog/product/a/i/aico-bcs-ks10-crsnth-cmp_1.jpg"
```

I updated the Image search path as   `media` and saved the configuration for image processor.

When I run the import, images are not imported.

I do not have images in media/import folder as I migrated data from an existing site.

I want to take images from `media/catalog/product`

I am getting warning as

```
Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - error copying media/catalog/product/a/i/aico-btho-5060-bmbzl-brn_1.jpg
```

Comment: magmi cannot copy a file on itself !!. move your media/catalog/product dir elsewhere & use it as source.

Comment: @dweeves Where should I move this directory? I have more than 100GB of images there. Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: just a hint:have you tried Image import mode:"keep existing images" in image plugin settings. it should check if target exists & avoid the copy. if problem still arise with this, then it might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks dweeves,If I am importing images from remote url.What should be the settings in image attribute processor.